# Find out the name of all the servers a paticular account has logged or has a disconnected session on it

Tags: active-directory, powershell

Hi We have around 400+ of servers and one domain + 3 sub domains,
 Whenever we change a password [Security reasons] the accounts keeps getting locked out as soon as we unlock it. So is there a way we can list all the servers or Workstations to list out if a user account is logged in or has a disconnected or idle session on it so that we logout.

Comment: Probably quicker and simpler to check the event logs on the domain controllers for the source of the lockouts.

Comment: @GregAskew - I had lockout problems myself only recently and I was told they could only retrieve that information if I called them withing 8 minutes of my account being locked and only for the server that locked it. Still being logged on into multiple servers, it took a while to get everything resolved. I'm not a sysadmin, so I have no idea about what *should* be possible.

Comment: Yes we figured out while the account is logged has a disconnected or ilde session with the old password it will keep getting locked. so we need to find out all the computers and logged out

Comment: @greg askew its easy to find out source of workstation where its getting locked, but when u log and logout the user after a while it will locked again from from another workstation where there is a idle of disconnected session..... and it keeps repeating

Answer (score 2):

Following rough proof of concept might get you started. The idea is to use Powershell to search eventlogs for logon/logoff events for a given SID.

1. Find SID using `(Get-ADUser <username>).SID` in Powershell
2. Execute in powershell

```
   $query = @"
   <QueryList>
     <Query Id="0" Path="System">
       <Select Path="System">
         *[EventData[Data[@Name='UserSid']='<SID>']]
         and (*[System[(EventID='7001')]] or *[System[(EventID='7002')]])
      </Select>
     </Query>
   </QueryList>
 "@
('server1', 'server2) | % {Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $_ -Filterxml $query -MaxEvents 1}
```

The xml filter returns only logon/logoff events. By only selecting 1 event using `MaxEvents`, you get a list for all servers you passed to the `Get-WinEvent` method with either a logon or logoff message. The logon messages are servers where that SID is still logged on.